# How to get mapPoint z coordinate by Lat and Lon

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Please see the map on:
https://codepen.io/stzdzyhs/pen/WamYav

the whole code is also inserted below.

When click on the scene(A IntegratedMeshLayer), it can show the Lon, Lat, and Z values in the SceneView onclick event.

however, how to query the Z value by inputting (Lon,Lat), e.g:
whether it has a function like:
double getZ(lon, lat);

the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<!--
ArcGIS API for JavaScript, https://js.arcgis.com
For more information about the layers-integratedmeshlayer sample, read the original sample description at developers.arcgis.com.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/layers-integratedmeshlayer/index.html
-->
<title>IntegratedMeshLayer - 4.6</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.6/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.6/"></script>
<style>
html,
body,
#viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script>
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/layers/IntegratedMeshLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
],
function(Map, SceneView, IntegratedMeshLayer) {
     // Create IntegratedMeshLayer layer
    var layer = new IntegratedMeshLayer({
        url: "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/FQD0rKU8X5sAQfh8/arcgis/rest/services/VRICON_Yosemite_Sample_Integrated_Mesh_scene_layer/SceneServer"
    });
    // Add IntegratedMeshLayer to map
    var map = new Map({
        //basemap: "satellite",
        layers: [layer]//,
        //ground: "world-elevation"
    });

    var view = new SceneView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        camera: {
            position: {
                x: -13314225,
                y: 4543000,
                z: 1446,
                spatialReference: {
                    wkid: 3857
                }
            },
            tilt: 84,
            heading: 85
        }
    });
    // show lon, lat, and Z  
    view.on("click", function(evt) {
        alert(evt.mapPoint.longitude + " " + evt.mapPoint.latitude + " " + evt.mapPoint.z);
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to include the code sample in the body of the question. External links are often not followed (often due to security concerns) and are subject to failure in the future, damaging the usefulness of the question question.

Answer (score 1):

The elevation in your example is not coming from the IntegratedMeshLayer - in fact if you remove that layer you'll notice that your click event with the "z" attribute will still work.

That z altitude data is coming from the [Esri World Elevation layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-ElevationLayer.html#) ([service](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7029fb60158543ad845c7e1527af11e4)), which gets added to the map by default when you set `ground: "world-elevation"` in your `Map(...)` constructor.

So to get the z value for the world evelvation layer, just use the [QueryElevation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-ElevationLayer.html#queryElevation) method.

Comment: Please copy the code, run local computer might easily reproduce following:  
1. place the mouse on the MeshLyr,NOT move mouse.use only keyboard,  change the code like:  
     var map = new Map({
     layers:[layer]
     });
click mouse,and record the z val(z0).   
2. use only keyboard to switch to code(NOT move Mouse) , and change the code like:  
    var map = new Map({
      ground:"world-elevation"
    });
click mouse, and record the z val(z1),   
that those two z values are not same.usaly,z0>z1  
looks like the z is from Mesh layer.(seems SO can not add newline in comments)